# Validating collection of attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm looking for a solution to validate presence of at least one attribute in collection of attributes. In my model I have a constant with bunch of attributes:

```
LANGUAGES = [:eng, :spanish, :german, :italian, etc]
```

Then I iterate over it in the view, setting each attribute to be a checkbox. I need to make sure that at least one checkbox is checked for the form to be valid. Here's my current custom validate method, but that's not working for some reason:

```
validate : validate_languages

private
def validate_languages
  LANGUAGES.each do |primary_language|
    language = self.send(primary_language)
    if self.language.blank?
      self.errors.add(:language, "You must select at least one option.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `self.language.blank? && !self.language.present?` srsly?

Comment: @zishe can you be more descriptive?

Comment: I think you figured out, since you've changed the post. It's obvious that enough only one of that conditions.

Comment: the implementation of the `.present?` method is `def present? ; !blank? ; end` (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/126dc47665c65cd129967cbd8a5926dddd0aa514/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L15) -- @zishe please be constructive, not aggressive, in your comments ...

Comment: Thanks @ekremkrc. So I need to use present? instead of blank? But doing this as well, still doesn't work. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
validates :language, presence: true, inclusion: { in: LANGUAGES }
```

Or re-invent the wheel:

```
validate :language_integrity

def language_integrity
  self.errors.add(:language, "Language can't be blank!") if self.language.blank?
  self.errors.add(:language, "Language is not standard") unless LANGUAGES.includes?(self.language.to_sym)
end
```

---

Following your first comment on this answer, you can do:

```
validate :language_integrity

def language_integrity
  LANGUAGES.each do |language|
    return true if self.send(language).present?
  end
  self.errors.add(:language, "Select at least one Language!")
end
```

Comment: that would work if I only had one attribute in the table. All of the attributes in constant are mapped to table's attributes. Hope this makes sense? Thanks for help though...

Comment: Awesome @MrYoshiji! This is working great, however, I am not getting red asterisk at the top level of collection, which is a bummer. Any thought on this? Really thanks so much for this!!!

Comment: Can you explain your point? I don't understand your sentence "I am not getting red asterisk at the top level of collection" @NicholasAlek -- also, accept the answer if it solved your initial question

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I think this is something I need to mess in my view. Basically, the label is set outside the collection loop, which makes asterisk not showing as required.